# CiviCRM and GDPR

Tags: contacts

To how large degree is CiviCRM GDPR-compliant. One example that I just now thought of is, what if someone calls us and wants all our records of correspondence deleted from our systems. Can I just delete the contact and all activities, memberships records, volunteering etc disappears? Or do I do a lot more than this to ensure I stay GDPR-compliant?

What are the plans to make CiviCRM GDPR-compliant (if such plans exist, or are considered)?

Answer (score 4):

There is work ongoing to ensure that CiviCRM is GDPR-ready. Veda Consulting is leading on this I think, and there's an extension in progress [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr) and some helpful background documentation [here](https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/GDPR).

Comment: Thanks, so currently it isn't but is planned to be well before May 2018 if I understand this correctly. The detailed doc in the links looks to be something that will be very useful to me so that's good.
Currently anonymizing the data is a mess, if read that "between the lines" correctly?

Comment: That's how I read it as well.

Answer (score 2):

We've just released a new version which has anonymisation built into it. Please do take a look.

https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr